# Dynamically style react native theme provider react native elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to dynamically style the React Native Elements Theme Provider using AsyncStorage or some sort of value retrieval ?

The Theme gets loaded in the app root index.js

```
const theme = () {
  light: {
    colors: {
      primary: colors.light,
      background: '#ffffff',
    },
  dark: {
    colors: {
      primary: colors.dark,
      background: '#ffffff',
    },
}
```

```
const Root = () => (
  <SafeAreaProvider>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
        <Toast ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </SafeAreaProvider>
);
```

Comment: Do you want to add styling when you have loading and another style when loading is finished ??

Comment: @Guku On the Start up of the app for the entire app ... using as little code as possible ... I'm trying to set the theme of the app by using async storage and trying to retrieve a value for a specific style, I can't male the root function async or use awaits so thats where my problem comes in